# Amcharts: How to get trendline slope?

Tags: amcharts, timeserieschart, trendline

How to calculate the slope or x,y coordinate of drawing trendline(drawn by user) in order to predict a future value? eg. the green trenline in this image [AmStockChart with drawing trendline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlP36.png)

Comment: first try something, then post

Answer (score 0):

The trendline functionality in AmCharts only takes start and end coordinates, so you'd have to calculate and create your own line. There is a [bestFitLine](https://github.com/amcharts/tools/tree/master/bestFitLine) plugin you can utilize that calculates a best fit trendline for you, however it isn't available for AmCharts' Stock Chart Library. If you're okay with using the regular AmCharts JavaScript Charts library then you can use that instead, oruse the plugin as a basis for a stock chart-compatible version.